# ARGB in tkinter ttk behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I've been trying to learn Tkinter and subsequently ttk to create a GUI. When working with ttk I noticed something peculiar happening. When I gave any colour in an ARGB format, `'#80FFFFFF'` for example, there was no error but the particular widget simply turned into a small square. Why does this happen?

Here is an example,

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()

s.configure('b1.TButton', background='#FF0000')
s.configure('b2.TButton', background='#80FFFFFF')

b1 = ttk.Button(root, style='b1.TButton')
b2 = ttk.Button(root, style='b2.TButton')

b1.grid()
b2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the result of this code: [image: Imgur]

Comment: After some testing and reading I believe it is because of the extra `FF` that tells the ARGB to be transparent. Seeing that Tkinter and transparency are a difficult if not impossible concept in tkinter it may be causing the button to act this way because it does not know how to display the button with transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter buttons do not support transparency so my thoughts is that the extra `FF` in your ARGB code that tells the color to be transparent is what is causing the issue.

My guess from my research is that the Button cannot format properly due to the transparency color code and thus causes this problem when displaying the button.

You can test this by adding FF to any ARGB color and see the same effect.

Comment: Yeah, but tkinter simply gives you an error when you give a color string of 8. Shouldn't ttk do the same?

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka not necessarily. TTK is a set of widgets that are similar to tk widgets but are designed to support styles. They are not carbon copies of the tk widgets so they may handle issues differently than the tk widgets would.